# How to set background-image to an image in your source folder?

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to display an image I have in my source folder as the background-image of my Jumbotron below:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(assets\images\bar.jpg); background-size: 100%;"></div>
```

The `assets/images/bar.jpg` path displays the image with a regular  tag, but it isn't appearing when used as a *url* above.

This is where my image is stored:
`src/assets/images/bar.jpg`

And here is where my HTML is:
`src/app/event-page/event-page.component.html`

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that this image is displayed in the background of my jumbotron? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to move 2 spaces back like `../../assets`

Comment: can you try this `background-image: url(assets/images/bar.jpg)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abdul Basit said, you need to do `../../assets/images/bar.jpg`
[image]